# I can't select every focus style in JS using document.querySelectorAll('*:focus')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I must select every focus background color style and have control on them to change their b.colors.

I write below code but it doesn't work:

When I wrote only `*` to selector, all wanted goals finish. However, when I add *:focus to selector, I can't change focus style background colors. Why?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

});

window.console = window.console || (function(){
    var c = {}; c.log = c.warn = c.debug = c.info = c.error = c.time = c.dir = c.profile = c.clear = c.exception = c.trace = c.assert = function(){};
    return c;
})();


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict"

    document.querySelectorAll('*,*:focus').forEach(function(node) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
        const color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
        const Bcolor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');

        if (color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

            $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("color", "red", "important");
                return false;
            });

            $("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("color", "pink", "important");
                return false;
            });

        }

            if (Bcolor === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

            $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");
                return false;
            });

            $("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
                node.style.setProperty("backgroundColor", "pink", "important");
                return false;
            });

        }


    });

        $("#color-style-switcher .bottom a.settings").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var div = $("#color-style-switcher");
            if (div.css("left") === "-195px") {
                $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                    left: "0px"
                });
            } else {
                $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                    left: "-195px"
                });
            }
        })

        $("ul.colors li a").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        })
});
```

Comment: Which line isn't working?

Comment: @Joundill It doesnt select *:focus things

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? The code currently iterates over **all elements in the DOM**, running `getComputedStyle` on each (a *very* expensive process). Then, if the color is a specific color, adds click event listeners to certain classes that will, eventually, set the color property of all of the elements with the previously mentioned color in the DOM to red or pink. This is very unusual behavior and I would question its utility. I would think it would be much easier to implement in CSS only...

Comment: It will only select elements which have the focus at the point that `jQuery(document).ready(` is called.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It is not answer.If you want do much easier thing, you must find uncountable class and id for every button,text,border etc. has same color.

Comment: so the easiest way echo the class and id via js then write new js function

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you up vote my question, If users get down vote for every question, nobody dont any question

Comment: I only upvote questions that meet the criteria to be upvoted; that is, questions that show research effort, that are useful and that are clear. I don't feel this question is clear, and as I mentioned, I don't understand what you are expecting to happen. This seems like it could be done in CSS itself if you have control over the CSS of the site.

Comment: @HereticMonkey After your noticed about jquery.document.ready, I changed my fixing straregy to echo related css classes via js, then as you said, change the style without select every class via js.So, for new question which you said that shown reseach effort, I must get upvoting.In other situation, nobody learn anything about codding when they get any error or they ask any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` selects **elements**. `*:focus` will select any element which currently has the `:focus` psuedo-class.

It does not select rule-sets. You can't use it to determine the style for an element that gains the focus in the future.

If you want to do that, you'll need to loop over the rule-sets using the [StyleSheet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList).

Comment: You didnt understand me or I didnt you.I want to change focus background color property for every things has same color.I mean the css changing but I dont understand what do you mean.